# Handle drop down on web page dialog selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, web, popupwindow

I am working on a automation of a  website using selenium and C# , but i stuck in a situation where on a button click a new webpage dialog open and on that web page dialog we have to select some value and click on save button. Problem is i am unable to switch to that webpage dialog and even f12 window not working on that webpage dialog this website is only working on IE so no other option . Please help me. Here is post screenshot of webpage dialog and HTML code of Button which open that dialog box.

[image]

Comment: <INPUT **onclick=showClose()**; id=ucTicketDetail1_btnClose title=Close style="BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px" src="../images/tasks.gif" type=image name=ucTicketDetail1$btnClose>

Comment: Have you tried driver.switchTo()? (considering it is a modal dialog)

Comment: What was the result? Apparently your dialog does not have a title

Comment: Sorry for late reply , result is xpath not found

Comment: Could you show us the way you are using `driver.switchTo` and the error you get with it?

Comment: I use following code.

Comment: IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='ucTicketDetail1_btnClose']"));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            PopupWindowFinder finder = new PopupWindowFinder(driver);
            string popupWindowHandle = finder.Click(element);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.SwitchTo().Window(popupWindowHandle);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath"//Select@id='cboRootCause']")).SendKeys("System Issue");

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unable to find element with xpath == //Select[@id='cboRootCause']

Answer (score 1):

I have got this problem, where the title of page is Webpage dialog same as you. In this window you can not inspect the element. Solution to this is go to

> ```
> Internet Explorer--> 
> Internet Options --> 
> Security tab -->
> Custom Level --> 
> Disable the option : Allow Websites to open windows without address or status bar
> ```

Now, You can inspect element by F12 in IE. now, simply write all the selenium commands, you can also use JavaScriptExecutor for that, If you dialog box calls JavaScript.